# Can't end jQuery fade on mouseout

Tags: jquery, mousehover, jquery-hover

I have a simple gallery style link setup using image swap on hover that I want to fade.  I'm currently 
using `

```
.stop().hide().FadeTo("slow",1);`
```

to fade in the image triggered by mousing over one of  the 
links on the left, here's a test site to see what I'm talking about

[testsite00.hostoi.com](http://testsite00.hostoi.com)

I can't figure out how to get the fade to end on mouseout.  I'm trying to create a seamless fade between links but the fade is repeating on mouseout.  Iv'e tried a number of combinations of .stop() and .hide() but can't seem to stop the effect from executing.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Image swap on hover
$("#gallery ul li img").hover(function(){   
$('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''))
  function() { //mouseenter handler 
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow",0.5);
  }
  function (){ //mouseleave handler 
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow",1.0);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <img src="images/gallery/home.png" alt="" id="main-img" />
   <ul>
     <li class="home"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/home.png" alt="" /></li>
     <li class="about"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/about us.png" alt="" /></li>
     <li class="contact"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Contact Us.png" alt="" /></li>
     <li class="services"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Services.png" alt="" /></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass true to your stop call to clear the animation cue, or true, true to clear the queue and immediately finish the animation:

```
.stop(true, true)
```

Also, you should pass two functions to your hover handler - what happens on mouseenter, then what happens on mouseleave - if you want it to reappear (or disappear - whatever the desired behavior is), that should go in the second function.

```
  $("#gallery ul li img").mouseenter(function(){
    var currentImg = $('#main-img').attr('src');
    var targetImg = $('this').attr('src').replace('thumb/', '');
    if (currentImg !== targetImg) {
      $('#main-img')
        .stop(true)
        .fadeTo(0,0)
        .attr('src', targetImg)
        .fadeTo('normal', 1);
    }
  });
```

So what this does is first check if the image being hovered over isn't already the thumbnail of the large image - no need to do the fade animation here. If it's not, then stop and clear the animation queue (to prevent animations from piling up on fast hovering), instantly fade the current large image to 0 opacity (make it invisible), change the big picture to that represented by the thumbnail, then fade the big picture in. The fade-in speed is currently set to "normal" but this can be "slow", "fast" or some millisecond value if you want to experiment with it. Gone is the hover function as you don't need any behavior on mouseleave.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my comment with what I think you mean.  It didn't seem to work :(

Comment: Thank you sir, this has been more than helpful, I'm still a noob when it comes to java-script and jQuery.                           $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''))   are actually the images in which I want to fade, should I  place your code here instead?  Thanks again.

Comment: Here is the code I'm using http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-image-swap-gallery/. the image URL that needs to be faded is obtained by getting the thumbnail URL and removing the “/thumb” What I have done is made different thumb images and  saved them to the same directory as the main images.

Comment: Ok, I see what caused the confusion - they unnecessarily used hover when all they needed was mouseenter. Do I understand correctly that you want to do the same thing, but just put a fade on the thumbnail that goes away when you stop hovering over the thumbnail?

Comment: Yes basically what I have are 4 thumbs and 4 large images.  The larger images should fade in when the corresponding thumb is hovered.  The fade in is fine when link  is hovered but when I mouse out of link, the fade repeats resulting in a double effect which isn't a big deal but would look better if there was only a fade in.  lol does this make any sense?  I'll load the test site again.

Comment: Ok the site is updated [link]http://.testsite00.hostoi.com The links on the left are my thumbs and the blue boxes on the right are the larger, or "main-img"

Comment: Ok, it's starting to make more sense - when you mouseenter on the thumbnail, fade in the large picture. When you mouseleave, what exactly should happen? Should the large image that you're fading in finish fading in? Should it just stay there like the example you showed?

Comment: Lol when mouse leave, the fade repeats, I am trying to get it to stop repeating so it just stays there without the extra fade when mouse leave, thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it now. I'll edit my code above and you try it to see if it does what you want.

Comment: Correction, you were right, the large image should finish fading in and not fade in again when mouse leave.

Comment: Wow, ok thanks! I tried a quick and dirty copy/paste lol.. didn't work at all so I'll have to play around with it tonight, hopefully it's just the CSS and it will work! I'll be sure to cite your code if/when the page is up and running.

Comment: Nah, no need to cite. It should work, I basically put this into the code for the example site you linked to and it worked. I think it looks better if you slow the fade more, however, so you may want to change normal to slow or experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you may be running into a common misunderstanding of what `mouseout` really does. Due to bubbling the event also triggers on child elements which is not really intuitive.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html

Try `mouseleave` and see if that works.